# Ruby on Rails 2 with Heroku: how do I install plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I did: heroku plugins:install `git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git`

And got

```
Could not initialize rails-ckeditor: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport

Are you attempting to install a Rails plugin? If so, use the following:

Rails 2.x:
script/plugin install git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git

Rails 3.x:
rails plugin install git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git
```

my gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'authlogic', '2.1.6'
gem 'addresslogic', '1.2.1'
gem 'searchlogic', '2.4.19'
gem 'subdomain-fu', '0.5.4'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DerNalia,

If I'm understanding you correctly I think you are misinterpreting what the heroku plugin install function is for. It's not for installing Rails plugins, it's for install plugins for the heroku command, like the heroku_colorize_console plugin. To install a plugin for your Rails application for Rails 2 you would use

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git
```

This would install plugin into your vendor/plugins directory in your application and be initialized based on it's init.rb file (which is executed automated when the site loads). Your heroku app would have it accessible once you commit the changes and deploy back up to heroku.

See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-cli-plugins for more details about the Heroku command and the plugins function.

Comment: I guess my problem is cause by the plugin then. cause locally, everything works, but i'm getting an error with search logic not having has_attached_file? ... and I don't use attachments, or that method... so.. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Well search logic is a gem though right? You might consider vendoring the gem into the vendor directory using the rake gem pack command.

Answer (score 1):

So what happened when you ran `script/plugin install git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git`?

The idea of a plugin is that it will end up in the vendor directory in your Rails project, not as a stand-alone install on the server (those are gems).

Comment: Are you committing the plugin into your git repository after you install it?

Comment: yup, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206276/ror2-8-heroku-i-installed-a-plugin-works-locally-now-heroku-doesnt-work-at