# RoR2.8 & Heroku: I installed a plugin, works locally, now heroku doesn't work at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

heroku logs brings up:

```
==> dyno-3334279.log (crash) <==
/app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/conditions.rb:81:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x2baaa6077e58> (NoMethodError)
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/association_conditions.rb:19:in `method_missing'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/association_ordering.rb:27:in `method_missing'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:28:in `method_missing'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1994:in `method_missing'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:2
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `each'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:411:in `each'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:411:in `load_application_classes'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:197:in `process'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:29
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /app/fd916ea6-bad5-440e-a560-405ef5e3beee/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
```

the plugin I installed

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git
```

I ran the migrations both locally, and on Heroku... 
I don't get this error locally... so.. any on the problem?
I don't use any files in my app... so this confuses me.

gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rails', '2.3.8'
gem 'authlogic', '2.1.6'
gem 'addresslogic', '1.2.1'
gem 'searchlogic', '2.4.19'
gem 'subdomain-fu', '0.5.4'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, I just needed to delete the models that rails-ckeditor created, as well as the migration file...

I'm not using files for this project, and they were screwy anyway. so.. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted the server on the heroku side? Also, has_attached_file, is that a paperclip method?

Update:

Can you run searchlogic on heroku like that?  I thought they wanted you to use their add-ons for searching?  I'm just trying to help debug, i don't know the answer.

Also, why does searchlogic need a paperclip method?  are you searching images in your heroku app?

Update 2:

What's on this line of the file:

`app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:2`

Please paste that file into your stack.  Or the first few lines anyways.
(why does ckeditor have it's own directory?)

Comment: I have. I even put the paperclip gem in my gemfile to see if it would fix the error, but the samething still happens.

Comment: you must be getting another error then, because in your update to the question the paperclip is not added to your gemfile, as you have it shown.

Comment: I didn't add it to the gemfile up there, because it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with images or files of anysort. I just installed the ckeditor-rails plugin, and this error showed up when I tried to push to heroku. If you could do the same, that would be awesome.

Comment: I removed the file, but here it is: https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor/blob/master/examples/models/paperclip/attachment_file.rb

Comment: this should work, if you add `gem "paperclip"` into your Gemfile. assuming you are using bundler with rails 2.3.8.  Once paperclip is loaded, along with this editor thing, it'll either work, or you'll get other errors. also, did you add the config stuff to allow rails to see that new model directory we discussed prior?